# Parse url string object into host name in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope variable that returns me an absolute url stored by the user. While displaying I would like to only show the host name for the given object.

for example.
 $scope.url ="www.myurl.com/zyas?nxs"

i want to only display it as www.myurl.com.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the below code

```
string s = "www.myurl.com/zyas?nxs";
string newstr = s.split("/"); //newstr == "www.myurl.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$scope.url ="www.myurl.com/zyas?nxs"

$scope.host = $scope.url.split('/')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var hostName = $scope.url.split('/')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In a better way, you can do this without splitting and doing things

```
  var url = new URL("http://www.myurl.com/zyas?dsfadf");
  console.log(url.host); // gives the host name www.myurl.com
```

Comment: I dont need to parse the url of my browser. what I need to do is parse teh URL i get in string from my database to its hostname only. Are there any filters like date filters in Angular that could parse it or should I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I went with the normal split provided by JavaScript. Here's how I parsed it to the hostname and pushed it back to my JSON object.

```
    $scope.blogposts = result.data
                // console.log(urls);
                $scope.blogposts.forEach(function(blog){
                    console.log(blog);
                var a = blog.url.split('/')
                // blog.push({'viewUrl':'a[0]'})
                blog["viewUrl"] =a[0]
            })
```